# .encode('utf-8') printing strange characters

Tags: python, utf-8

I have some text in the form of a python string that represent foreign names:

```
Graziano Pellè
Sergio Agüero
Cesc Fàbregas
```

I am encoding the string with the syntax:

```
(string).encode('utf-8')
```

However this prints:

```
Graziano PellÃ¨
Sergio AgÃ¼ero
Cesc FÃ bregas
```

This happens when the string is printed to both Command Shell and Python Shell, but I don't understand why. I was of the impression that the universal character set supports alphabets from most major languages. If this is not the correct encoding to use, what should I use instead?

Thanks

Comment: Please specify whether you're using Python 2 or Python 3

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen hi, thanks for replying. i'm using python 2.7.

Comment: And what happens if you don't specifically encode your strings? Sounds like you're double-encoding your strings. (...Python 3 is much nicer because it has true Unicode strings by default.)

Comment: Encoding transforms logical strings into the bytes that represent those strings in that encoding. If you print out the raw bytes, you should indeed see the output you're getting -- that's what those strings look like in UTF-8.

Comment: @Cameron: No, that's not what those strings look like in UTF-8. UTF-8 is bytes, not characters, and on a UTF-8 or UTF-8-ish terminal (like any Mac, most Linux boxes, or a Windows box set to that buggy code page they call "Unicode" that I forget the number of), those bytes will be displayed exactly the way he wants. That's only what those strings look like when encoded in UTF-8 *and then interpreted as Latin-1*.

Comment: @abarnert: Good point. The view of the bytes is skewed by how they are interpreted (I've grown too used to Windows' latin-1 console, heh). I suppose the only way to really see the bytes properly is to look at the individual byte values, e.g. with a hex editor.

Comment: @Cameron: Yeah, it's always hard to answer these kinds of questions without immediately jumping to "First learn how to use a hex editor, then the rest will be easier to explain"… Anyway, I've been spoiled by Mac, Linux, and FreeBSD boxes that are all UTF-8, and it's easy to forget that there are still a few people in the world who use the most popular desktop OS in history. :) But the last time I had to use Windows as a dev box, I had to use Shift-JIS, the only modern charset that isn't a pure ASCII superset, which is a great way to force yourself to think straight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your terminal window (I assume `cmd.exe`, because this sounds like Windows) is not UTF-8, but some Latin-1-like character set like Windows-1252.

So, you encode those Unicode strings as UTF-8 byte sequences, then send those to the terminal, which interprets those UTF-8 byte sequences as if they were Windows-1252 byte sequences, and displays them as garbage.

For example, `u"Graziano Pellè"`, when encoded to UTF-8, is:

```
'Graziano Pell\xc3\xa8'
```

Why? Well, in UTF-8, ASCII characters encode to one byte, so `G`, aka U+0047, becomes the single byte `0x47`, which looks like a `G` in almost any character set, but non-ASCII characters encode to two or more bytes, so `è`, aka U+00E8, becomes `0xc3` and `0xa8`. In Windows-1252, `0xc3` is the character `Ã`, and `0xa8` is the character `¨`.

---

The easy solution here—if your Python is properly detecting your terminal's character set—is to just print the Unicode strings directly.

If not, you have to look up the character set in some way (or just hard-code it, if this is only for local use; it's probably `cp1252`, but you can find it in your System Preferences as "OEM Code Page") and encode to that, instead of to UTF-8.

---

One last thing:

> I was of the impression that the universal character set supports alphabets from most major languages.

It does.* But the problem is that you can't just write Unicode to the console; you have to write bytes.** And the question becomes, which bytes? If you write UTF-8 bytes, and the terminal is expecting cp1252 bytes, you get mojibake.

<sub>* Actually, "the universal character set" usually means ISO-60464 or UCS 2, not modern Unicode… but they're the same for the first 61K characters or so, so let's pretend that's close enough…</sub>

<sub>** This isn't actually true on Windows; you can instead write 16-bit words, and they're guaranteed to be interpreted as UTF-16. But Python 2.x doesn't know how to use the Windows console that way, so that doesn't help you unless you want to start making Win32 API calls directly instead of using friendly things like `print`.</sub>